# exception while deploying spring app on tomcat 6

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat6

I'm trying to make a simple web app using spring and deploying it on Tomcat 6. When I try to deploy it on the server, it gives me the following error. I'm unable to figure out if the problem is with Tomcat or my app.

```
Feb 12, 2010 3:45:43 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SpringPOC' did not find a matching property.
Feb 12, 2010 3:45:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.5.0_15\bin;.;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.5.0_15/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.5.0_15/bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Windows Imaging\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_15\bin
Feb 12, 2010 3:45:43 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Feb 12, 2010 3:45:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 737 ms
Feb 12, 2010 3:45:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Feb 12, 2010 3:45:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.20
Feb 12, 2010 3:45:43 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
SEVERE: End event threw exception
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.callMethodN(IntrospectionUtils.java:956)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.CallMethodMultiRule.end(WebRuleSet.java:789)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Rule.end(Rule.java:229)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1140)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1644)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationWebConfig(ContextConfig.java:365)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.start(ContextConfig.java:1066)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:261)
      at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4339)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:722)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:583)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name profile
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:2470)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:2450)
      ... 35 more
Feb 12, 2010 3:45:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig applicationWebConfig
SEVERE: Parse error in application web.xml file at jndi:/localhost/SpringPOC/WEB-INF/web.xml
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name profile
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2808)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2834)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1143)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1644)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationWebConfig(ContextConfig.java:365)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.start(ContextConfig.java:1066)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:261)
      at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4339)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:722)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:583)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Feb 12, 2010 3:45:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig applicationWebConfig
SEVERE: Occurred at line 8 column 23
Feb 12, 2010 3:45:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig start
SEVERE: Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s)
Feb 12, 2010 3:45:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
Feb 12, 2010 3:45:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/SpringPOC] startup failed due to previous errors
Feb 12, 2010 3:45:43 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Feb 12, 2010 3:45:43 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Feb 12, 2010 3:45:43 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/31  config=null
Feb 12, 2010 3:45:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 635 ms
```

My app tries to take the users name in one page and on submit displays a welcome message on another page saying "good day, <username>!"

Can anybody please help make sense of this exception?

Thanks,
Neetu.

Comment: Could you paste your web.xml file? seems the problem lies there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exception disappeared after I moved the spring jars into the web-inf's lib folder from the web-inf folder.

Comment: Yeah, you might need those :). Maybe you should delete your other answer (the one with the web.xml file) and mark this (yours) as the correct one. If you need to add info to another question you make, just edit it, don't add answers to it. Good to know you solved it!

Comment: Thanks Pablo :) Not able to delete the web.xml post below and can mark this one as correct only tomorrow.

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem lies here:

```
Parse error in application web.xml file at jndi:/localhost/SpringPOC/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

And here:

```
Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name profile
```

Seems like you want to map a server to a given path like for example:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>profile</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

but you're missing that servlet definition like so:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>profile</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

Probably a typo?

Answer (score 0):

### web.xml

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

SpringPOC

```
   <servlet-name>profile</servlet-name>

   <url-pattern>/profile</url-pattern>
```

```
  <servlet-name>profile</servlet-name>

  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

</servlet>
```

profile